# I'm trying to find the latex symbol for a logical notation... Analogy: the symbol is to "logical and" as $\Sigma$ is to summation

Tags: logic

I'm trying to find the latex symbol for a logical notation... Analogy: the symbol is to "logical and" as $\Sigma$ is to summation.

For example if I want to "logical and" over sentences with varying indices, what is the notation for this?

For example $(x_1 \land x_2 \land x_3 ... \land x_n)$ can be written $?_{1\leq i \leq n} \space x_i$. The "?" is the symbol I am looking for.

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate on [tex.se]?

Comment: From the Help Center: "And some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: [...] Typesetting equations — you can read our guideline for writing equations on this site, or visit the TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange for questions about TeX and friends".

Comment: My apologies, didn't know that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want \bigwedge: $\bigwedge_{i<n}\varphi_i$